# Algebraically Proving $f(x)=\sqrt{x-1}+2x$ is injective

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

How can I Algebraically (without using calculus) prove $f(x)=\sqrt{x-1}+2x$ is injective.

Comment: Both $\sqrt{x-1}$ and $2x$ are strictly increasing

Comment: your function is defined for $x\ge1$; could you solve a quadratic equation to get a unique suitable $x$ for each $f(x)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Injectivity means :
$f(a) = f(b) \Rightarrow a=b$

which is equivalent to  : $a \neq b \Rightarrow f(a) \neq f(b)$

Notice that $a \neq b \Rightarrow a>b$ or $a<b$.

WLOG, let $a>b$. Then $2a > 2b$ and $\sqrt{a-1}>\sqrt{b-1}$.

You take the sum and obtain $$2a + \sqrt{a-1} > 2b + \sqrt{b-1}$$

So $f(a)>f(b) \Rightarrow f(a)\neq f(b) $ QED

But when (if) you write the proof, make sure to do it rigorously by defining the domain of $f$ and all that stuff..